# Print a field in a set display mode

Tags: 7, theming

I can print a field in content type tpl file with this:

```
<?php echo render($content['field_name']); ?>
```

But how can I print the field as a different display mode?

EG I might always want to print the teaser version of an image field, regardless of what view mode is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a shortcut to this but I don't know it...

```
// Get the bundle settings.
$info = field_info_instance('node', 'field_name', 'content_type');

// Get the field render array
$build = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name', $info['display']['teaser']);

// And print it
print render($build);
```

Moving the display building logic to a preprocess function would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry but you've misunderstood my question. I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: @jdln I've had another go :)

Comment: Its not printing anything for me. The only bits ive changed are 'field_name','content_type' and 'teaser', is that correct?

Comment: Yep that's correct. I just tried the code on a site of mine and it works fine. Have you replaced `field_name` in both places?

Comment: I was expecting my display mode to be 'my_display_mode' but actually the machine name is 'mydisplaymode'. Working fine, thanks.